# Efficient construction of correlation matrix—serial correlation

Tags: correlation, covariance-matrix, matrix-decomposition, stan, correlation-matrix

Given $\rho$, is there a way to efficiently construct this matrix (i.e., as a product of matrices, rather than using a for loop)?

$$
\Sigma = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \rho & \rho^2 &\cdots & \rho^k\\
\rho & 1 & \rho & \cdots &  \rho^{k-1} \\
\rho^2 & \rho & 1 & \cdots & \rho^{k-2}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\rho^k & \rho^{k-1} & \rho^{k-2} & \cdots & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I am trying to use this in STAN to define a multivariate normal prior distribution where adjacent components of the variable have correlation $\rho$, but I assume that simply constructing $\Sigma$ using nested for loops would be rather inefficient. I would appreciate any advice for addressing this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is including one foo-loop but vectorized so maybe numerically fast in matlab, R or numpy.

Step 1: Construct integer matrix $K$.
$$
\begin{align}
K &:= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 & \cdots & k \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & k-1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & k-2 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \end{bmatrix} \\ &= \left( \operatorname{ReLU} (j - i) \right)_{ij}
\end{align}
$$
where $\operatorname{ReLU} (x) := \max (0,x)$. Note that one for-loop is used here.

Step 2: Make it symmetric, get $E := K + K^{T}$ where $K^{T}$ denotes a transpose of $K$.

Step 3: Calculate componentwisely, $\rho^{E}$.

Here is my julia implemetation, but maybe you can easily port to your language.

```
julia> ρ = 2
2

julia> k = 5
5

julia> ReLU(x) = max(0, x)
ReLU (generic function with 1 method)

julia> K = [ReLU(j-i) for i in 1:k, j in 1:k]
5×5 Matrix{Int64}:
 0  1  2  3  4
 0  0  1  2  3
 0  0  0  1  2
 0  0  0  0  1
 0  0  0  0  0

julia> E = K + K'
5×5 Matrix{Int64}:
 0  1  2  3  4
 1  0  1  2  3
 2  1  0  1  2
 3  2  1  0  1
 4  3  2  1  0

julia> ρ .^ E
5×5 Matrix{Int64}:
  1  2  4  8  16
  2  1  2  4   8
  4  2  1  2   4
  8  4  2  1   2
 16  8  4  2   1
```

And if you have some matrix operation, like `Symmetric` in below code, then cost to power will be reduced about half.

````
julia> using LinearAlgebra

julia> K = [ReLU(j-i) for i in 1:k, j in 1:k]
5×5 Matrix{Int64}:
 0  1  2  3  4
 0  0  1  2  3
 0  0  0  1  2
 0  0  0  0  1
 0  0  0  0  0

julia> E = ρ .^ K
5×5 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2  4  8  16
 1  1  2  4   8
 1  1  1  2   4
 1  1  1  1   2
 1  1  1  1   1

julia> E = Symmetric(E)
5×5 Symmetric{Int64, Matrix{Int64}}:
  1  2  4  8  16
  2  1  2  4   8
  4  2  1  2   4
  8  4  2  1   2
 16  8  4  2   1
```
````